# Is it ok to declare same window events multiple times in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, performance, events

I have a few elements listening to window resize and scroll events. In order to make the code clear for reading, I declared same window events multiple times in different blocks, like the following...

```
$('#foo')...
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('#foo')...
});

// lots of code...

$('#bar')...
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('#bar')...
});

// and so on..
```

where I believe generally it should be written as

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('#foo')...
    $('#bar')...
});

// lots of code

$('#foo')...

// lots of code

$('bar')...
```

My question is, will it make any difference to jQuery performance if I declare window events multiple times?

Comment: Yes, you can cache the objects:  `var $window = $(window)`

Comment: @undefined The question is not about caching jQuery object selection; It is about adding multiple (?) `resize` events.

Comment: @pst Yes, he is creating same jquery objects multiple times, I thought that can be a useful point.

Comment: @pst yep, I think undefined got a point there. If I do `var $window = $(window);` And then `$(window).bind('resize scroll', function() {$window = $(window);});` I'm always using the cached window event. But I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it. btw, nice username, undefined.

Comment: No. That's *not* using a "cached window event". Whatever that is supposed to do/mean, it looks wrong. In any case, `$(window)` can be thought of as a "no appreciable cost" operation (it is `O(1)` for a very small `C`).

Comment: @pst uhh...yes it's not cached...:( `var $window = $(window);` `alert($window.width());` // 1333 `$(window).resize(function() {alert($window.width());});` // 1903 I'v just got a response from jQuery forum says **There is very little performance difference**

Comment: @user1643156 Precisely: *this argument to/for "caching" the jQuery object is pointless* and *not related* to the question at hand as it has *nothing* to do with events.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but minimal. JQuery will have to go through one extra callback in the resize queue. Big deal, right?

Consider this too, your code is making 2 function calls:

1. `$()`
2. `resize()`

You can do these to improve:

1. Cache your `$(window)` call (like @undefined said in the comment) into a variable. Doing this will reduce the call to `$()`.
2. Try to use `on('resize', function(){})` for better optimization (according to jQuery documentation)